# Firebase auth - Phone sign-in method not rendering correct SMS messages template for IOS

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I have a Firebase project where I set up auth so users can log into app using cell phone.
Its a react native app and Ive built for both IOS and Android.
In the project settings I populated the "Public facing name" field with "myAppName"
When the SMS text is generated to users logging in on Android, the user is given "myAppName"....but on the ios side they are given the projectID (project-xxxx.firebaseapp.com).
Below is the template in Firebase for SMS verification
`%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%`.
The `%APP_NAME%` variable is what is rendering differently on Android vs IOS....in Android its rendering as "Public facing name"...but in IOS its rendering as Project ID"

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your `APN` to firebase.

> ```
> Upload your APNs authentication key
> Inside your project in the Firebase console, select the gear icon, select Project Settings, and then select the Cloud Messaging tab. In
> ```
>
> APNs authentication key under iOS app configuration, click the Upload
> button.

You can read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)